# Custom Paperclip::Processor with AWS S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

This code works fine if the uploads are stored locally, but sometimes they are on S3 so it's not possible to just `source: "#{File.expand_path(src.path)}[0]"`. How do I make the Paperclip's `run` method load images from S3 and replace them afterwards?

```
module Paperclip

  class KskCrop < Processor

    def initialize(file, options = {}, attachment = nil)
      super
      @crop = options
      @format = File.extname(@file.path)
      @basename = File.basename(@file.path, @format)
    end

    def make
      src = @file
      dst = Tempfile.new([@basename, @format])
      dst.binmode

        parameters = []
        parameters << ":source"
        parameters << "-crop '#{@crop[2]}x#{@crop[3]}+#{@crop[0]}+#{@crop[1]}'"
        parameters << ":dest"

        parameters = parameters.flatten.compact.join(' ').strip.squeeze(' ')

        success = Paperclip.run('convert', parameters, source: "#{File.expand_path(src.path)}[0]", dest: File.expand_path(dst.path))

      dst
    end

  end
end
```

Comment: you can use url for any uploaded image at s3 but are they getting uploaded,if yes then you can simply access using @image.avatar.url where avatar is your paperclip attachment with has_attached_file:avatar...pls see below for more info

Comment: what does `src.path` gives when it is uploaded to s3? is it relative path? or complete path?

Comment: @Surya It's a relative path "/assets/files/000/000/583/original/Screen_Shot_2014-05-13_at_16.59.42.png"

Comment: can you try: src.url? If you can, then do something like this: stackoverflow.com/a/2517286/645886 and then process it. Honestly, I don't think if it is possible to process an image on a CDN. You have to have that image on a server(better if it's local system where you're running the operations).

Comment: @Surya thanks it helped. I've answer the question to show what needs to be done. you can also submit an answer and receive the bounty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Looks like this is the solution!**

```
module Paperclip

  class KskCrop < Processor

    def initialize(file, options = {}, attachment = nil)
      super
      @crop = options
      @format = File.extname(@file.path)
      @basename = File.basename(@file.path, @format)
    end

    def make
      src = @file
      dst = Tempfile.new([@basename, @format])
      dst.binmode

      parameters = []
      parameters << ":source"
      parameters << "-crop '#{@crop[2]}x#{@crop[3]}+#{@crop[0]}+#{@crop[1]}'"
      parameters << ":dest"

      parameters = parameters.flatten.compact.join(' ').strip.squeeze(' ')

      path = if @file.options && @file.options[:storage] == :s3
        src.url
      else
        File.expand_path(src.path)
      end
      success = Paperclip.run('convert', parameters, source: path, dest: File.expand_path(dst.path))

      dst
    end

  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

So, as per the conversation. It turned out that path has to be a complete url instead of a relative path. Hence, this line will look something like this:

```
success = Paperclip.run('convert', parameters, source: src.url, dest: File.expand_path(dst.path)
```

As, OP has already answered his question with an `if.. else`. I think that's a better approach to check if the attachment is on a local file or on a CDN.

P.S.: I also learned that `Paperclip.run(..)` method  can actually locate and download a file for processing if it's a url without making an IO operations at developer's end.

Answer (score 0):

well i didnt got your question well but for Amazon S3 READ/WRITE, this is what is use...

**this is my s3.yml**

```
development:
  bucket: app_development
  access_key_id: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  secret_access_key: xxxxxxxxxxxxx+xxxxxxxxxxx
production:
  bucket: app_production
  access_key_id: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  secret_access_key: xxxxxxxxxxxx+xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

**my config/initializers/paperclip.rb**

```
    Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = ':s3_domain_url'
    Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = '/:class/:id/:style/:filename'
##will store in the foll way shown below in the bucket u specify in s3.yml
##http://app_development.s3.amazonaws.com/videos/1/original/small.mp4

    ##if Rails.env == "production" 
       #S3_CREDENTIALS = { :access_key_id => ENV['S3_KEY'], :secret_access_key => ENV['S3_SECRET'], :bucket => "ourbucket"} 
     ##else 
       S3_CREDENTIALS = Rails.root.join("config/s3.yml")
    ##end
```

**so after this configuration,any paperclip model with has_attached_file:avatar will get uploaded on s3**

```
##upload to s3..code snippet (can also use in _form.html.erb as f.file_field :avatar)
@video=Video.create!({ :avatar => File.new("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/dashboard/default_avatar.jpg")      
        })
##this is how u can display/access any uploaded object/model using url(which shows original unless you specify some styles -thumbnail,small)
@video.avatar.url
@video.avatar.url(:thumbnail)
@video.avatar.url(:small)
```

Comment: Please look up what Paperclip::Processor does. I have no trouble storing default processed pictures to s3.